Manipulating infinity when proving the equivalent conditions for conditional expectation
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative (maybe take $\infty$) $\mathcal F$ measurable random variables.
Show $\forall A \in \mathcal F, E(X1_A)=E(Y1_A)$ iff $\forall Z $ non-neagtive, $ \mathcal F$ measurable random variable, $E(XZ)= E(YZ).$
One direction is obvious. For the other one the proof is by a common fashion, I only got a small problem when dealing with the limit.
We can approximate $Z$ pointwise by a sequence of increasing non negative real rvs $Z_n$.
So $E(XZ)= E(X \lim Z_n)= E(\lim X Z_n) = \lim E(XZ_n)$
$X\lim Z_n = \lim XZ_n$ is a little bit confusing.

$X(\omega) =0$, then followed from convention $0 \times \infty =0$, we have the results.
$X(\omega) \in \Bbb{R}-\{0\}$, obvious from calculus, even if $Z_n$ diverge to $\infty$.
$X(\omega) =\infty$,

If $\lim Z_n= 0$, all $Z_n=0$
If $\lim Z_n= \in \Bbb{R}-\{0\}$, at least one $Z_n$ is not zero, so $\lim XZ_n= \infty$
If $\lim Z_n= \infty$, at least one $Z_n$ is not zero, so $\lim XZ_n= \infty$.
Do I really need to deal with all of these cases? Any simple ways?
